# Istio Token Validation via Proxy

Tags: validation, kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

Istio supports `AuthZ` and `AuthN` services, but is there a way to implement a token validation via a proxy?

Example: User/Client sends a request to Service-A, the request hits to istio-ingressGateway and Gateway validates the token via another service (Validation Service) if the token is valid user/client can get the user data if not send an error equivalent response.

[image: Visual Example]

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use? Why do you want to have external validation service? Did you see [this page](https://medium.com/intelligentmachines/istio-jwt-step-by-step-guide-for-micro-services-authentication-690b170348fc)?

Comment: Kubernetes 1.21, Istio: 1.11.2, Yes I read this page. To validate token with in house service or via [oauth2-proxy](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2021/better-external-authz/) social connections

Comment: Please look at [this doc](https://getindata.com/blog/oauth2-based-authentication-on-istio-powered-kubernetes-clusters/). It could help you. Please let me know if yes or not.

Comment: This was the second blog I found while searching oauth2-proxy with istio, he uses Envoy Filter for authorization, but latest istio provides external authorization
Today I was successful in redirecting unauthorized request to oauth-proxy2 with istio external authorization, now facing problem after authentication says login failed CSRF token not found

Comment: Implemented this method sucessfully will share a blog if got time 

Comment: If you still have problem with CSRF token, please create new question.

Comment: Follow up have also implemented In house Basic Validator Service on istio ingressgateway

Answer (score 0):

You can write a micro-gateway service using [Netflix Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) which will be the landing service from your Istio Gateway. It can do quick token validation using `Zuul filters` and then forward the request to the desired service or return a token error response. You can use this service for issuing tokens and also hosting the JWK keys for JWT tokens.
[I've written a Java implementation for the same.](https://blog.devutkarsh.com/api-microgateway-service-using-netflix-zuul-on-java/)

Otherwise, you can use an internal Nginx server as a landing for all your request and then use `http_auth_request_module` to do a quick auth and then proxy forward to other services. You can find it on [Nginx documentation.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything as such provided by Istio as of now.

Comment: What about the AuthZ server, istio has a istio External Authorization could that be used ?

Comment: Yes that can be tweaked and used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Posted community wiki answer for better visibility. As [Tushar Mistry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10106978/tushar-mistry) mentioned in the comments - problem is solved based on [this article](https://getindata.com/blog/oauth2-based-authentication-on-istio-powered-kubernetes-clusters/):

> This was the second blog I found while searching oauth2-proxy with istio, he uses Envoy Filter for authorization, but latest istio provides external authorization Today I was successful in redirecting unauthorized request to oauth-proxy2 with istio external authorization, now facing problem after authentication says login failed CSRF token not found

and later:

> Implemented this method sucessfully will share a blog if got time.

See also [Better External Authorization](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2021/better-external-authz/).